# Flutter Firebase Reqd one document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a landing page and a collection in firestore that i save some  information about a user in (e.g if he passed the On Boarding Screen or not). The next time i open the app, i want to check if the user passed the onboarding. If they did: I redirect to another screen; if not, then redirect to onboarding.

All the examples are reading a collection and get all documents, but i need to read only one document which i know the documentid .

i have tried to get the data like this, but did not work.

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  // LandingPage({@required this.auth});
  // final AuthBase auth;
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context, listen: false);
        return StreamBuilder<User>(
          stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              User user = snapshot.data;
                  if (user == null) {
                return ChooseLanguage(
                    //     auth: auth,
                    );
              }

    // he i need to do a call to a ducment in the firestore
    //if the retuen is true then i go to page 1 else go to page 2

            } else {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

do i have to do -iama beginner in flutter

Answer (score 2):

To get one document do the following:

```
getData()async{
await Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(id).get().then((value){
      print(value.data['name']);
    });
}
```

You need to use the correct `collection` name, `value.data` will contain the data of that document which you can access using the `[]` operator.

---

According to your edit, you are checking if `checkonboarding()` is null, but since it returns a future you need to use await:

```
    void sendData()async{
        bool value = await checkonBoarding(user);
      if (value != null) {
            return Provider<Database>(
              create: (_) => new FireStoreDatabase(uid: user.uid),
              child: Dashboard(usr: user, auth: auth),
            );
          } else {
            return Provider<Database>(
              create: (_) => new FireStoreDatabase(uid: user.uid),
              child: Onboarding(usr: user, auth: auth),
            );
          }
       }
```

Comment: bool checkonBoarding(User user) {
    bool x = false;
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      if (value.data['onboarding']) {
        user.onBoardingValue = value.data['onBoardingvalue'];
        x = true;
      } else {
        x = false;
      }
    });
    return x;
  }
thi sisithe code i use , its reaches "  .then((value) {' the jumbs to return x and iam sure that there os data

Comment: i want to put the code in a function that return bool but it is not working  "  if (checkonBoarding(user) == true)"  its gives me :"Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types."

Comment: but what is this problem and how can i solve it if u know

Comment: if you are using `async` then it will return a `Future`, so you should do `getData.then((val){if(!val){...});`

Comment: @ peter i have edited the question will full code can u check it

Comment: `     if (checkonBoarding(user) != null) {
            return Provider<Database>(
              create: (_) => new FireStoreDatabase(uid: user.uid),
              child: Dashboard(usr: user, auth: auth),
            );
          } else {
            return Provider<Database>(
              create: (_) => new FireStoreDatabase(uid: user.uid),
              child: Onboarding(usr: user, auth: auth),
            );
          }` this code should be inside a method

Comment: the problem is the the call to the function is inside  "
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {" and if i call the sendData the buidl is giving that there is no return -- iam posting all file code